# Java : double method returning (the sum of array values)

Tags: java, arrays

When returning a double value in the method the return doesn't work , but when calling this **System.out.println(EnergyPerDay_Wh);** it shows the value i would like to know how to get **EnergyPerDay_Wh** as a return value for a method, the method is this:

```
public double CalculateEnergyPerDay() {

        double TotalPower = 0 ;
        double EnergyPerDay_Wh = 0 ;

        Device [] DEVICE = new Device [3] ;



        for(int j=0 ; j <= 3 ; j++)

        {       

            DEVICE [j]  = new Device();

            DEVICE[j].NumberOfItems    =   1         ;//---------------> user input

            DEVICE[j].Power_W          =   1         ;//---------------> user input

            DEVICE[j].HoursOfUsage_H   =   1         ;//---------------> user input

            TotalPower = DEVICE[j].NumberOfItems * DEVICE[j].Power_W * DEVICE[j].HoursOfUsage_H ; 

            EnergyPerDay_Wh += TotalPower ;

        }


        System.out.println(EnergyPerDay_Wh);


        return EnergyPerDay_Wh;
}
```

i tried different approaches it didn't work even with the **double** or **string** or with changing the **outPut stream and then saving it into a string variable**

calling the method:

```
public class EBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        TakingInput ti = new TakingInput(); 

        ti.CalculateEnergyPerDay();

    }
```

**TakingInput** is the class that has the method

Comment: So it doesnt work even if you change the return type to `double`? How and where do you call the method?

Comment: my bad i copied the code and didn't change the type sorry . but it didn't work when changing the type to double as well

Comment: @Zebri it doesn't work what is wrong???

Comment: What `getDeviceInfoAndCalculateEnergyPerDay()` does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're calling a method called `getDeviceInfoAndCalculateEnergyPerDay` while your method is actually called `CalculateEnergyPerDay`.

Also, you need to do something with the value the method returns. For example print it out:

```
System.out.println(ti.CalculateEnergyPerDay());
```

Comment: thanks for the good advice . but i made a small mistake while copying the code i was changing the returns hoping to get the output. but even when it was double it didn't  work ,, what is wrong???

Comment: your are the best my bad

Comment: i'm ashamed of myself right now :(  , but thank you for you answer

Answer (score 0):

you declared to return `String` and returning `double`

Answer (score 0):

Change method return type to Double

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a small mistake about the method signature. At the top you declared the method as string and you are returning a double value.

You could either change the method signature to double:

```
public double CalculateEnergyPerDay()
```

Or you could do this to return a string value:

```
return ""+EnergyPerDay_Wh;
```

Comment: thanks for  the good advice . but i made a small mistake while copying the code i was changing the returns hoping to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

use String.valueOf(EnergyPerDay_Wh); in your method. your method will not compile unless you either change return type or return string as mentioned above.